# Put TAB in selectbox's option list

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

How can I put TAB inside itens in selectbox's option itens?

I have:

```
<select>
    <option>Tese - Teste de descrição</option>
    <option>Mais um - De desc.</option>
    <option>tabulação - Item de tabulação com info</option>
</select>
```

I wanna:

```
<select>
    <option>Tese        Teste de descrição</option>
    <option>Mais um     De desc.</option>
    <option>tabulação   Item de tabulação com info</option>
</select>
```

Update: Ok, vbTab or Chr(9) do it:

```
<select>
    <option>Tese<% Response.Write Chr(9) & Chr(9) & Chr(9) %>Teste de descrição</option>
    <option>Mais um<% Response.Write Chr(9) %>De desc.</option>
    <option>tabulação<% Response.Write Chr(9) & Chr(9) %>Item de tabulação com info</option>
</select>
```

but I could only see it in source code. The browser isn't rendering it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately in HTML is not specified a TAB character.

In order to achieve the result you are looking for you can generate the options in the selection box padding with non breaking spaces (`&nbsp;`) the string where you were adding the vbTab. You can try this:

```
<%
    Function Rpad (sValue, sPadchar, iLength)
      Dim result=""
      For i=0 to i=iLength - Len(sValue)
          result = result & sPadchar
      Next
      Rpad=result
    End Function
%>

<select>
    <option><% Response.Write Rpad("Tese","&nbsp;",10)  %>Teste de descriзгo</option>
    <option><% Response.Write Rpad("Mais um","&nbsp;",10)  %>De desc.</option>
    <option><% Response.Write Rpad("tabulaзгo","&nbsp;",10)  %>Item de tabulaзгo com  info</option>
</select>
```

Sorry but I can't try if my code actually works so maybe you have to thweak it a little. I hope you get the sense of it.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. My real situation is the example. I create that selectbox with a loop in a database... but the result is that one... I was hoping to use the tab to get a better reading (this is my real objective);

Comment: I was asking for the code you've used to concatenate with vbTab without success, so I can work out a solution for a similar behaviour using `&nbsp;`. The result I want to achieve is to emulate the tab with white spaces padding.

Comment: The only way you will be able to achieve this is to set your font to a fixed width and then, as misleadingTitle states, use &nbsp; for the correct number of characters. `<option>Mais um&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;De desc.</option>`.

Comment: I've update the code for my intended solution. The result is like @Westie suggestion, but programmatically achieved.